# Aloquei memória dinamicamente de um vetor em C, não retorna o tamanho alocado, por que?

Tags: c, array, memória, malloc, sizeof

Esse código é uma exemplificação de outro código com o mesmo problema. Aloquei a memória dinamicamente, mas quando vou imprimir o tamanho do vetor com o `len`, estranhamente imprime 1 e não 10 como esperado. O segundo `for` imprime os 10 valores corretamente. Por que não imprime 10 no `len`?

```
int main()

    int *vetor;

    vetor = (int*)malloc(10*(sizeof(int)));

    for(int i=0; i<10 ; i++)
    {
        vetor[i] = i+1;
    }

    for(int j=0; j<10 ; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",vetor[j]);
    }

    int len = (int)(sizeof(vetor)/sizeof(vetor[0]));

    printf("\n%d",len); //Len retorna 1 no

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível fazer essa operação, o padrão que está usando é adequado para *array*, o que está usando não é um *array*, ainda que pareça. Isso é um ponteiro para um item e você sabe que existem vários deles então pode navegar com o ponteiro pelos itens seguintes como se fosse um *array*, mas não é.

O `sizeof` é um operador que resolve o valor ali em tempo de compilação, ele não pode ser usado para algo que será resolvido em tempo de execução.

A única forma de saber a quantidade de itens dessa sequência é adotar um padrão que guarde esse valor ou que conte quantos itens tem, se adotou algum terminador na sequência (é o que a *string* do C faz).

Se for guardar o mais simples e bastante usado é só manter uma variável com esse valor, então toda API que precisa receber esse ponteiro terá que receber junto essa valor da quantidade itens para controlar o acesso. Outras forma usada é criar uma `struct` que faça um único objeto ter o tamanho da sequência e a sequência (isso pode ser um problema em alguns compiladores). Também pode usar só um `#define` global, faz sentido em certos códigos.

O código pode ser bem melhor escrito e fazer mais sentido:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TAMANHO 10

int main(void) {
    int *vetor = malloc(TAMANHO * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < TAMANHO ; i++) {
        vetor[i] = i + 1;
        printf("%d\n", vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d", TAMANHO);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/v5jNj2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/SizeMallocc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/SizeMalloc.c).